# OpenMPI C programming fail

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I can't understand why this mpi c code works with matrix 7x7, but with matrix 8x8 and biggest have this fail:

**mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node ubuntu
exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).**

Why this happening?

Code:

```
#include "mpi.h" 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 7             
#define MASTER 0        
#define FROM_MASTER 1   
#define FROM_WORKER 2   

void Get_matr(int (*matr)[N], int n, int (*temp_matr)[N], int indRow, int indCol) {
    int ii = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(i != indRow){
            for (int j = 0, jj = 0; j < n; j++){
                if (j != indCol){
                    temp_matr[ii][jj] = matr[i][j];
                    jj++;
                }
            }
            ii++;
        }
    }
}

int Det(int (*matr)[N], int n) {
    int temp = 0;       
    int k = 1;          

    if(n < 1){
        printf("Input bigger matrix!!!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
        temp = matr[0][0];
    else if (n == 2)
        temp = matr[0][0] * matr[1][1] - matr[1][0] * matr[0][1];
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int m = n - 1;
            int temp_matr[m][m];
            Get_matr(matr, n, temp_matr, 0, i);
            temp = temp + k * matr[0][i] * Det(temp_matr, m);
            k = -k;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int numtasks,                   
        taskid,
        numworkers,                 
        source,                     
        dest,                       
        mtype,                      
        det,                        
        rows,                       
        averow, extra, offset,       
        i, j, k, errorcode;
    int a[N][N];                    
    double c[N][N];                 
    double starttime, endtime;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);

    if (numtasks < 2 ) {
        printf("Must be minimun 2 tasks!!!\n");
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, errorcode);
        exit(1);
    }

    starttime = MPI_Wtime();

    numworkers = numtasks-1;

    if (taskid == MASTER) { 

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                a[i][j] = rand()%9 + 1;

        printf("Matrix:\n");
        for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
            printf("\n");
            for (j=0; j<N; j++)
                printf("%d ", a[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");

        det = Det(a, N);

        printf("Determinant: %d\n", det);

        if (det == 0 ) {
            printf("Matrix with determinant=0 do not have inverted matrix!!!\n");
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, errorcode);
            exit(1);
        }

        averow = N/numworkers;              
        printf("Rows for each worker: %d\n", averow);

        extra = N%numworkers;               
        printf("Extra rows for workers: %d\n", extra);

        offset = 0;                         

        mtype = FROM_MASTER;
        for (dest=1; dest<=numworkers; dest++) {
            rows = (dest <= extra) ? averow+1 : averow; 

            MPI_Send(&det, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&a, N*N, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            offset = offset + rows;
        }

        mtype = FROM_WORKER;
        for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++) {
            source = i;
            MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&c, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        }


        printf("\nInverted matrix:\n");

        for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
            printf("\n");
            for (j=0; j<N; j++)
                printf("%6.2f ", c[j][i]);
        }

        printf ("\n\nNICE WORK!\n");
        endtime = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("working time: %f\n", endtime - starttime);
    }


    if (taskid > MASTER) {
        mtype = FROM_MASTER;
        MPI_Recv(&det, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&a, N*N, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        for(int i = 0; i < rows+offset; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                int m = N - 1;
                int temp_matr[m][m];

                Get_matr(a, N, temp_matr, i, j);

                c[i][j] = pow(-1.0, i + j + 2) * Det(temp_matr, m) / det;
            }
        }

        mtype = FROM_WORKER;
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&c, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }

   MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: You hardwired `N` with `#define N 7`. Do you change `N` when you compile with higher number of processors? Also `a` is a 2D array so pass it as `MPI_Recv(a, N*N, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);`

Comment: Same goes for `c` as well. Change it to `MPI_Send(c, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`. Also, change corresponding send/recv.

Comment: I applied your changes, but problem still remains. Fail occurs in Det function. When I add something like printf("%d", n); in Det function,  "Segmentation fault" not occur. But program works very slowly.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler complain when you pass `temp_matr[m][m]` to `Get_matr()` for the 3rd argument since one is `[][m]` while the other one `[][N]`. So the sizes do not match.

Comment: After I changed `temp_matr[m][m]` to `temp[m][N]` in two places the code compiled and is working for `N > 7` also without seg fault.